# Is the right annihilator of an element in a ring a subring?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

let $R$ be a ring and let $x$ not equal to $0$ be a fixed element in R. Then is $\{r \mid xr=0\}$ a subring of $R$?

The solution says yes, but I don't think so, because the multiplicative identity is not always included.(e.g. R = Z4, and x = 2) Any ideas?

Comment: Not all sources agree on the definition of ring. Some require it to have an identity, some don't. Check which definition your book uses. In any case, $I = \{ r \mid rx = 0 \}$ is a left ideal.

Comment: Im using the one that does. The one that does not require an multiplicative identity is call rng.

Comment: Then either the solution given is inconsistent with the text of the book, or the definition of *subring* extends this terminology to sub *rngs*.  In any case, it boils down to a matter of definitions.

Comment: By the way, deligne has certainly chosen a most honorable user name for his/ her self!

Comment: Dear @deligne : I think the response to Henry's comment was a little off. You can have two rings with identity $R\subseteq S$ where $R$ doesn't contain the identity of $S$. $R$ would still be more than just a *rng*, and yet some books would say $R$ isn't a subring because it doesn't have $S$'s identity. Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can show that:

- Your set is always a right ideal of $R$. Moreover, you could consider it a rng contained in $R$ since it's closed under multiplication (and is an abelian subgroup of $(R,+)$.)
- There's no guarantee it will be a ring with identity. But it can happen: if $x$ commutes with elements of $R$ and $x^2=x$, then the set you gave is a ring with identity $1-x$.
- It *cannot* be a subring that shares the identity with $R$. That would imply that the identity $1$ of $R$ is in the set, so that $x=x1=0$, but by assumption $0\neq x$.

Answer (score 1):

For $0 \ne x \in R$, setting

$S(x) = \{r \in R \mid xr = 0\}, \tag{1}$

then it is easy to see that i.) $0 \in S(x)$, since $x0 = 0$; ii.)  $r, s \in S(x) \Rightarrow r + s \in S(x)$, since $xr = xs = 0 \Rightarrow x(r + s) = xr + xs = 0$; iii.)  $r \in S(x) \Rightarrow -r \in S(x)$, since $x(-r) = -rx = 0$; iv.) $r, s \in S(x) \Rightarrow rs, sr \in S(x)$, since $xr = xs = 0 \Rightarrow x(rs) = (xr)s = 0s = 0$ and $x(sr) = (xs)r = 0r = 0$.  Thus $S(x)$ is closed under the operations of $R$ and contains $0 \in R$, the additive identity.  It thus follows that $S(x)$ satisfies all of the ring axioms with respect to the operations of $R$.  But if the one's accepted definition of "ring" includes *necessarily* the existence of a multiplicative unit, then $S(x)$ is *not* a subring of $R$, since $1_R x = x 1_R = x \ne 0$, so $1_R \notin S(x)$.  In my experience, most authors would not insist the definition of "ring" include a multiplicative identity, reserving a term such as "unital ring" for those that do have a $1_R \in R$.  So I would say that, under the usual, conventional definition of a ring, $S(x)$ is indeed a subring of $R$.

Hope this helps.  Cheers,

and as always,

***Fiat Lux!!!***