# For a fixed element of a ring R, show that the set is a subring of R.

Tags: abstract-algebra

The question follows. For a fixed element of a ring R, show that the set $S=\{x\in \mathbb{R}|ax=0\}$ is a subring of R.

To show that S is a subring of R, it must meet the following conditions:

$(i) S \neq \emptyset$

$(ii) x \in S$ and $y \in S$ imply that $x-y$ and $xy$ are in S.

This is my proof:

$(i) $ Since S is a subring of R, then the additive identity is in S. Thus $a*0=0 \rightarrow 0=0$ and $0\in S$. Thus $S \neq \emptyset.$

$(ii)$ Let $x,y \in S$, then $ax=0$ and $ay=0$. Thus $a(x-y)=0 \rightarrow ax-ay=0 \rightarrow 0-0=0.$ Thus $x-y\in S.$ Which also following with $xy$.

Let $x,y \in S$, then $ax=0$ and $ay=0$, then $a(xy)=0 \rightarrow (ax)y=0 \rightarrow 0*y=0 \rightarrow 0=0$, thus $xy \in S.$

Is it right? any modifications that I can do to make it better?

Comment: Compare your proof with [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/946619/is-the-right-annihilator-of-an-element-in-a-ring-a-subring) by Robert. You will see yourself what you can do better.

Comment: Will do, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the right ideas, you just need to write them down better. For instance, you want to *prove* that $S$ is a subring, so you cannot start with “since $S$ is a subring of $R$”. Also the argument in (ii) is backwards.

Avoid those pesky arrows! `;-)` It seems that you start from $a(xy)=0$ (which instead is what you *need* to prove) and deduce that $0=0$. But $0=0$ can be deduced from everything, even from a false assumption!

#### Revised version

(i) Since $a0=0$, we see that $0\in S$, so $S\ne\emptyset$.

(ii) Suppose $x,y\in S$. Then $ax=0$ and $ay=0$ by definition; so
$$
a(x-y)=ax-ay=0-0=0
$$
and therefore $x-y\in S$. Similarly,
$$
a(xy)=(ax)y=0y=0
$$
which proves $xy\in S$.